# Avoid prop-drilling query arguments in RTK Query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, rtk-query

At the root of my app I make a `getUserQuery` that accepts an `id` and returns a user object. Throughout the rest of my application are a large number of places where other queries are made that need the `id` of the user as one of the params passed to their queries.

I thought I'd be able to select the `user` from the `apiSlice`, in order to access its `id`, but I can only do that if I know what params were used to make the query (the user `id`) which defeats the point of selecting the user to get its `id`.

I know I could pass the user down through the UI, but this is ugly. I also understand that I could do it with Context, but again this doesn't feel right. Given that the `getUserQuery` was made and cached (and I know that `getUserQuery` will only ever be made for a single user), it feels like there must be more sensible way for me to access the user's `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redux-Toolkit Query is only an API cache management solution, there's really no sense of "state" *other than* what queries have been made and what their cached results were/are, e.g. their metadata.

Using a React context seems sensible enough to me to keep track of any current/active/recently-used "id" query parameter.

If creating an entire React context doesn't "feel right" you could always store the "current" id in your Redux store. Use the query's [`onQueryStarted`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi#onquerystarted) property to dispatch an action to store the currently used "id" value.

Example:

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const idSlice = createSlice({
  name: "id",
  initialState: null,
  reducers: {
    setId: (state, action) => action.payload,
  }
});

export { setId } = idSlice.actions;

export const idSelector = state => state.id;

export default idSlice.reducer;
```

```js
import { createApi } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';

export const apiSlice = createApi({
  ....,
  endpoints: builder => ({
    ...

    getUserQuery: builder.query({
      query: id => {....},
      onQueryStarted: async (id, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) => {
        try {
          await queryFulfilled;
          dispatch(setId(id));
        } catch(error) {
          // Handle or ignore? Up to you.
        }
      },
    }),

    ...
  }),
});
```

In the UI use the `useSelector` hook and the `idSelector` selector function to select the most recently set "id" value.

```js
const id = useSelector(idSelector);
```